# InstantiationException when using SQLData and OracleCallableStatement Struct Mapping

Tags: oracle, object, jdbc, struct, mapping

I cannot figure out an answer to the following problem. Hope somebody can help me. I am mapping JAVA class to a Struct as described here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/samapp4.htm

I have an Oracle Object:

```
create or replace TYPE DK1 AS OBJECT( zahl CHAR(1) );
```

and corresponding JAVA class:

```
public class DK1 implements SQLData {

  private String sql_type;
  public static final int _SQL_TYPECODE = OracleTypes.STRUCT;
  private String zahl;

  public DK1(String sql_type, String z) {
    this.sql_type = sql_type;
    setZahl(z);
  }

  public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
    return sql_type;
  }

  public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
    sql_type = typeName;
    this.setZahl(stream.readString());
  }

  public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
    stream.writeString(getZahl());
  }

  public String getSql_type() {
    return sql_type;
  }

  public void setSql_type(String sql_type) {
    this.sql_type = sql_type;
  }

  public String getZahl() {
    return zahl;
  }

  public void setZahl(String zahl) {
    this.zahl = zahl;
  }
}
```

my test method is the following:

```
public class SQLDataExample {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

    OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@................", "...",
        "...");

    Dictionary<String, Class<?>> map = (Dictionary) conn.getTypeMap();

    map.put("BONI.DK1", Class.forName("com.gwb.db.objects.DK1"));

    OracleCallableStatement cs = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call BOX.DK(?)}");

    DK1 dd = new DK1("BONI.DK1", "1");

    cs.setObject(1, dd);

    cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "BONI.DK1");

    cs.execute();

    DK1 df = (DK1) cs.getObject(1);
  }
}
```

Now, the last step

```
DK1 df = (DK1) cs.getObject(1);
```

in this procedure fails and although I have tried so many things in the last couple of days, I cannot get it to run! I get a

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Inconsistent Java-
>   ans SQL-Objecttypes: InstantiationException: com.gwb.db.objects.DK1

If I replace getObject with getSTRUCT I see that the DB procedure works and returns values as expected. I cannnot figure out why a I unable to map a JAVA Object.

I would be very grateful for any help or tipps! 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the default constructor

public DK1() { }